# Combining dependent observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a container class `Project` that has lots of `IItem`s in it. The project can have items added to it until it is started. Then no more items can be added to it, unless it is stopped.

Each item can in turn be activated and deactivated via its `IsActive` property.

```
public interface IItem 
{
    bool IsActive { get; set;}
}

public interface IFoo : IItem
{
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}

public interface IBar : IItem
{ }

public class Bar : IBar
{ 
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}

public class Project
{
    public Project(params IItem [] items)
    {
        Items = new List<IItem>(items);
    }

    public List<IItem> Items { get;}
}
```

I also have two observables one for the state of the project and one for changes to any items. I have simulated these with subjects for the purpose of this example

```
var projectIsRunningObservable = new Subject<bool>();
var projectItemChangedObservable = new Subject<IItem>();
```

I am trying to create an `IObservable<bool>` that sends a value indicating whether (at least one item is active and the project is started). If there are active items and the project is stopped it should push through a `false` value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void Main()
{
    var bar1 = new Bar();   
    var bar2 = new Bar();   

    var foo1 = new Foo();
    var foo2 = new Foo();

    var projectIsRunningObservable = new Subject<bool>();
    var projectItemChangedObservable = new Subject<IItem>();

    var project = new Project(
        bar1, bar2, foo1, foo2);


    var observable = Observable.Create<bool>(obs =>
                {
                   IList<IItem> items = null;

                    var stateObservable = projectIsRunningObservable.StartWith(false).Subscribe(
                    (state) =>
                    {
                        if (!state)
                        {
                            items = null;
                            obs.OnNext(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            items = project.Items.ToList();
                            obs.OnNext(items != null && items.Any(i => i.IsActive));
                        }
                    },
                    ex => obs.OnError(ex),
                    () => obs.OnCompleted());

                    var itemChangedObservable = projectItemChangedObservable.Subscribe(
                    x =>
                    {
                        obs.OnNext(items != null && items.Any(i => i.IsActive));
                    }
                    ,
                    ex => obs.OnError(ex),
                    () => obs.OnCompleted());

                    return new CompositeDisposable(stateObservable, itemChangedObservable);
                });


    var subscr = observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.WriteLine("Change bar1");
    bar1.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(bar1);

    Console.WriteLine("Change bar2");
    bar2.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(bar2);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo1");
    foo1.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo1);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo2");
    foo2.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo2);

    // Start project

    Console.WriteLine("Starting project");
    projectIsRunningObservable.OnNext(true);

    Console.WriteLine("Change bar1");
    bar1.IsActive = false;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(bar1);

    Console.WriteLine("Change bar2");
    bar2.IsActive = false;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(bar2);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo1");
    foo1.IsActive = false;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo1);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo2");
    foo2.IsActive = false;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo2);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo2 back to true");
    foo2.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo2);

    // Stop project
    Console.WriteLine("Stopping project");
    projectIsRunningObservable.OnNext(false);

    Console.WriteLine("Change bar1");
    bar1.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(bar1);

    Console.WriteLine("Change bar2");
    bar2.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(bar2);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo1");
    foo1.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo1);

    Console.WriteLine("Change foo2");
    foo2.IsActive = true;
    projectItemChangedObservable.OnNext(foo2);
}
```

This works, however I am not sure if it is the best way of doing this and also whether it is possible to send multiple `OnError` and `OnCompleted` notifcations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for `Observable.Create`. You should refactor `Subject` as `Observable`, and use the `TestScheduler` class for testing.

The answer to your latter question can be found in the [Rx Design Guidelines (PDF)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219). Chapter 6.2 states that `Observable.Create` provides several protections to make the sequence follow Rx contract.

> When the observable sequence has finished (either by firing OnError or Oncompleted), any subscription will automatically be unsubscribed.
>    Any subscribed observer instance will only see a single OnError or OnCompleted message. No more messages are sent through. This ensures the Rx grammar of OnNext* (OnError|OnCompleted)?

Note: that in the guidelines example, they use `Observable.CreateWithDisposable`. In the latest Rx release, it has been refactored into an overload for `Observable.Create`, as you probably know :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn't know `Observable.Create` automatically unsubscribes any subscriptions on `OnError` and `OnCompleted`. Handy tip!

Comment: @NedStoyanov - All observables should automatically dispose when they complete (error or otherwise).